# How to get rid of the footer when create an html from an excel file with python

Tags: python, html, excel

Hi: Im creating an HTML from an excel file who has just 1 sheet. Im dont want to use any vb macro, just python code. I can create my HTML but when I open it, I have the excel footer in the HTML showing me the sheet name. I want to get rid of that. This is my code:

```
from win32com.client.gencache import EnsureDispatch


from win32com.client import constants



yourExcelFile = 'C:\REPORT.xlsx'


newFileName = 'C:\REPORT.html'


xl = EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')


wb = xl.Workbooks.Open('C:\REPORT.xlsx')


wb.SaveAs(newFileName, constants.xlHtml)


wb.Close(True)


xl.Workbooks.Close()


xl.Quit()


del xl
```

The error is that it keeps showing the excel footer in the HTML page.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why don't you use a regular expression to remove it manually?

Comment: how can I use it from Python?

Comment: I tried to close excel of several ways but the footer still appears.

Comment: This footer gives me the sheet name... its a gray bar. Its not possible to remove it manually

Comment: I think it may have to be with the fact Im converting the whole workbook and not just the sheet...

Comment: show html source of the footer please.

Comment: @Loïc  Im programming in python....I want to get rid of the frame that shows the number of the sheet

Comment: report.html contains html right? Edit it with your favorite text editor, and you'll find what lines you want to remove.
Then create a regex matching those lines, so you can dynamically remove them with python.

Comment: @LoïcThis is the source code for the frame:

    <body topmargin=0 leftmargin=0 bgcolor="#808080">

    <table border=0 cellspacing=1>

     <tr>

     <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" nowrap><b><small><small>&nbsp;

    <a href="sheet001.html" target="frSheet"><font face="Arial"
     color="#000000">Sheet1</font></a>&nbsp;</small></small></b>      </td>

     </tr>

    </table>

    </body>

How would you do the regex?

Comment: Im sorry but Im trying to edit my comment above, but something is going on, I cant edit it...

Comment: just remove the frame... check beautifulsoup.

Comment: but this is the part where I cant connect, so I can remove the frame before creating the html from python???

Comment: just after `del x1` open the html file, and do your regular expression on it before saving it.

Comment: @Loïc I reviewd regular expressions, I dont really know how to implemented. Can you please show me how I can do the match between the frame that its not created yet and what I have?